# itext7 merging documents created by HtmlConverter.convertToDocument and perserving outlines

Tags: itext7

My two documents are created using HtmlConverter.convertToDocument and afterwards merged into one PDF:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfDest));

PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf, false, true).setCloseSourceDocuments(true);

// Convert
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(resourceFolder);
OutlineHandler outlineHandler = OutlineHandler.createStandardHandler();
converterProperties.setBaseUri(".");
converterProperties.setOutlineHandler(outlineHandler);
```

The first document contains "HTML Ipsum Presents" bookmark and the second one "Plastic_parts_Basic" and "Amo" (with children) .

Note the use of outline handler. After the merge, it seems that the bookmarks are getting mixed it. It makes sense considering that OutlineHandler for each document creates destinations following the same pattern:

```
OutlineHandler addOutline(ITagWorker tagWorker, IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
    String tagName = element.name();
    if (null != tagWorker && hasTagPriorityMapping(tagName) && context.getPdfDocument() != null) {
        int level = (int) getTagPriorityMapping(tagName);
        if (null == currentOutline) {
            currentOutline = context.getPdfDocument().getOutlines(false);
        }
        PdfOutline parent = currentOutline;
        while (!levelsInProcess.isEmpty() && level <= levelsInProcess.getFirst()) {
            parent = parent.getParent();
            levelsInProcess.pop();
        }
        String content = ((JsoupElementNode) element).text();
        if (content.isEmpty()) {
            content = getUniqueID(tagName);
        }
        PdfOutline outline = parent.addOutline(content);
        String destination = DESTINATION_PREFIX + getUniqueID(DESTINATION_PREFIX);
        outline.addDestination(PdfDestination.makeDestination(new PdfString(destination)));

        destinationsInProcess.push(destination);

        levelsInProcess.push(level);
        currentOutline = outline;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Clicking on the "Header level 2" in the bookmarks will point to the second header in the last merged document ("Amo"):

[image]

I tried to extend the class OutlineHandler, but the method I would need to change (getUniqueID) is private and thus invisible in the superclass.

Is there a way to get unique destinations across multiple documents created out of html?

The source files (java and html) and resulting PDFs (look at the RFQMerge.pdf) are here:
[the source code, files and result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ketzsjzm4fanxzd/stackoverflow.zip?dl=0)

The accepted answer did not work for me, I kept getting NullPointerException in the second line of this code:

`PdfDictionary names = targetPdf.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
 names.put(PdfName.Dests, replaceDict);`

Here is the cource code and the input/source code files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg7vsb0j3hbkfca/stackoverflowClarification.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please could you check you dropbox link? It seems to be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is as follows: iText generates pdf with the same outline names and does not resolve them during a merge (instead iText logs a warning and replaces the old destination with a new one).

There are two ways of handling the described situation:

1) Create pdfs with unique outline names. 
Unfortunately, right now the implementation of OutlineHandler is too private and that's impossible to override it properly. However you can build a custom version of pdfHTML for your needs. The repo is located at https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml and you are interested in the reset method of OutlineHandler :

```
 /**
 * Resets the current state so that this {@link OutlineHandler} is ready to process new document
 */
public void reset() {
    currentOutline = null;
    destinationsInProcess.clear();
    levelsInProcess.clear();
    uniqueIDs.clear();
}
```

Just comment its last line and build the jar.

2) Rename the document's destinations if you know that they cause some troubles.
Even though `PdfMerger` just replace the old destination with the new one, it logs a warning about it. You can get the names of the destination which have been overrided and rename them manually before a merge.

To follow this way, one should:
a) update the destination names:

```
    PdfNameTree destsTree = updateDestNamesDocument.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
    PdfNameTree newNameTree = new PdfNameTree(updateDestNamesDocument.getCatalog(), PdfName.Dests);
    for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : destsTree.getNames().entrySet()) {
        newNameTree.addEntry(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    PdfDictionary replaceDict = newNameTree.buildTree();
    replaceDict.makeIndirect(updateDestNamesDocument);

    PdfDictionary names = updateDestNamesDocument.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
    names.put(PdfName.Dests, replaceDict);
```

b) update the outlines:

```
    PdfOutline rootOutline = updateDestNamesDocument.getOutlines(false);
    updateOutlines(rootOutline, prefix);

    private void updateOutlines(PdfOutline parentOutline, String prefix) {
    for (PdfOutline outline : parentOutline.getAllChildren()) {
        updateOutlines(outline, prefix);
    }
    if (parentOutline.getDestination() instanceof PdfStringDestination) {
        parentOutline.addDestination(new PdfStringDestination(prefix + ((PdfString)parentOutline.getDestination().getPdfObject()).getValue()));
    }
}
```

And then you can successfully merge your pdfs.

Comment: my code throws Nullpointerexception on names.put(PdfName.Dests, replaceDict);. The catalog in updateDestNamesDocument contains only /Outlines /Type and /Catalog. Also, out of curiousity: whatdoes the replaceDict.makeIndirect(updateDestNamesDocument);?

Comment: Then the names dictionary is null, am I right? Do you still have any links in this document?

Comment: As it's stated in the javadoc: ` Marks object to be saved as indirect.`. Basically, it creates a separate object in a pdf tree for the dictionary.

Comment: The names dictionary is indeed null. When you by "links" mean outlines/bookmarks, yes, they are there. I am going to attach the code and the input/output files to the original question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @ Uladzimir Asipchuk - see above please

Comment: That's correct that `targetPdf.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names)` returns null. iText upates the catalog only on `close()`, and the document hasn't been closed up to this moment.

I suggest that you close and reopen the document

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Uladzimir Asipchuk for your answer it has worked for me.

I have slightly changed based on my requirement, my requirement is to merge two or more pdf that can be created from html or already created pdfs or both.

I have faced some issue while calling rebuild() method

```
PdfDictionary replaceDict = newNameTree.buildTree();
replaceDict.makeIndirect(updateDestNamesDocument);
```

**com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indire
cts.**

So, I have just added it as a new Entry with custom name and updated the same on outlines as well. It is working

```
try {
    String prefix = "cus-" + (index) + "-";
    PdfNameTree destsTree = pdf.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
    PdfNameTree newNameTree = new PdfNameTree(pdf.getCatalog(), PdfName.Dests);
    for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : destsTree.getNames().entrySet()) {
        newNameTree.addEntry(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : newNameTree.getNames().entrySet()) {
        destsTree.addEntry(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +"==>>"+ entry.getValue());
    }


    PdfOutline rootOutline = pdf.getOutlines(false);
    updateOutlines(rootOutline, prefix);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Mapping the newly added destination to outlines

```
public static void updateOutlines(PdfOutline parentOutline, String prefix) {
    for (PdfOutline outline : parentOutline.getAllChildren()) {
        updateOutlines(outline, prefix);
    }
    if (parentOutline.getDestination() instanceof PdfStringDestination) {
        parentOutline.addDestination(new PdfStringDestination(prefix + ((PdfString) parentOutline.getDestination().getPdfObject()).getValue()));
    }
}
```

This has been working properly for me do merge after this changes so all your destinations looks unique and it will not get override while merge.